# Error al comumir un servicio con ocelot y net 5

Tags: net, microservices, netcore

Les agradeceria su ayuda..

Tengo un microservicio creado y publicado con net 5 y funciona normal.

Ahora tambien he creado un proyecto net 5 con ocelot 17. pero al momento de consumir el servicio me presenta el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración en el startup es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración del program es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración del ocelot es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, el puerto lo declaro entre comillas, y otra cosa que te hace falta es declarar el tipo de método que vas a utilizar, ya sea GET, PUT, POST, ETC, si probaste directamente tu API, lo cual no veo el nombre del controlador, solo API, no tendrías problemas, ignora el NameController, pero de netcore sería mala práctica no usarlo, igual debes versionar tus apis

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/NameController/{catchAll}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "ip_server_public",
          "Port": "7103"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/NameController/{catchAll}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET"
      ]
    }
```